# Tried installing fastai on Spyder, but dont know how to solve this error

Tags: python, spyder

Can some help me with exact solution, I tried installing pytorch of different versions though but it is still getting the same.

```
!pip install fastai
```

```
Collecting fastai
  Using cached fastai-2.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (193 kB)
Collecting spacy<3
  Using cached spacy-2.3.5-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (9.7 MB)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torchvision<0.9,>=0.8 (from fastai) (from versions: 0.1.6, 0.1.7, 0.1.8, 0.1.9, 0.2.0, 0.2.1, 0.2.2, 0.2.2.post2, 0.2.2.post3, 0.5.0, 0.9.0, 0.9.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torchvision<0.9,>=0.8 (from fastai)
```

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) The right way to install packages in Spyder is not by using the `!pip` or `!conda` commands (which will be disabled in the future).

Instead, you need to install [Miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html), create a [conda environment](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands) after that with the packages you want to use and `spyder-kernels`, and finally [connect Spyder](http://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html#using-existing-environment) to that env.